# Evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{1}{x}\int _0^x\cos\left(t\right)dt\:$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

I think that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{1}{x}\int _0^x\cos\left(t\right)dt\:$ is divergent, I can prove with taylor series?

Comment: Why Taylor when you can integrate? It is in fact convergent to $0$.

Comment: The function
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t)dt
$$
oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. Divide by $x$, and let $x$ increase.

Comment: @Arthur with Taylor's series: $cos\left(x\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+...$ , $\int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt\ge \int _0^x\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dt=x-\frac{x^3}{6}\:\:\rightarrow \:\infty $ which is divergent, so where I was wrong?

Comment: What you've shown is that the integral in question is greater than $-\infty$ because the $x^3$ term dominates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be, since $\lvert \cos{t} \rvert<1$, so the integral is bounded between $x$ and $-x$. It could oscillate, but not diverge. However,
$$ \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} \cos{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{x} (\sin{x}-\sin{0}) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}, $$
which tends to $0$ since it is absolutely bounded by $1/x$, which tends to $0$.

Comment: with Taylor's series: $cos\left(x\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+...$ , $\int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt\ge \int _0^x\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dt=x-\frac{x^3}{6}\:\:\rightarrow \:\infty $ which is divergent, so where I was wrong?

Comment: @Lucas For higher values of $x$ you cannot cut away the higher degree terms like that. Cutting away higher degree terms only works for $x$ close to $0$.

Comment: @Arthur can you give me an example, to understand... please

Comment: Lucas: graph $\cos(x)$, and graph $1-x^2/2$. Is the second one *really* always bigger than the first?

Comment: No, the issue here is that your function is $1-x^2/6$, which actually tends to $-\infty$. What you've proved is that the expression is bigger than something that tends to $-\infty$, which doesn't say much. Taking the next term, i.e. $1-x^2/2+x^4/4!$, shows that the expression is smaller than something that tends to $+\infty$, and so on.

Comment: @Unit For the real numbers, yes, $\cos{x} \geqslant 1-x^2/2$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Chappers when help me Taylor's series ? when I use and how helps me?

Comment: @Lucas I'm not quite sure what you mean, but that sounds like a very broad question, possibly even too broad for this site, let alone a comment.  I suggest you ask another question, carefully worded, with a couple of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int_0^x \cos(t)dt=\sin(x)$$ Hence, we have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle \int_0^x \cos(t)dt}x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sin(x)}x = 0$$
since $\dfrac{\sin(x)}x \in \left[-\dfrac1x,\dfrac1x\right]$.

Comment: with Taylor's series: $cos\left(x\right)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+...$ , $\int _0^x\:f\left(t\right)dt\ge \int _0^x\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)dt=x-\frac{x^3}{6}\:\:\rightarrow \:\infty $ which is divergent, so where I was wrong?

Comment: @Lucas You are using a Taylor expansion around $0$, to "prove" divergence at $\infty$. *This* is wrong (how can you truncate terms that are unbounded?). The limit is also wrong anyway: when $x\to+\infty$, $x-x^3/6$ does not tend toward $+\infty$, but $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Such limit is zero, because $x\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ implies $\int_{0}^{x}\cos y\,dy=0$ and for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$ \int_{x}^{x+\pi}|\cos x\,|\,dx \leq 2,\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \left|\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\cos y\,dy\right|\leq\frac{2}{x}\to 0.\tag{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

Note that, $\int_0^x \cot (t)dt = \sin(x)$. Now, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)/x = 0$. Therefore,   $\frac1x \int_0^x \cot (t)dt = 0.$

Note- Sorry for typing it in a hurry, I was a bit busy while I typed the solution so thats why I couldn't type in latex. I'll update it as soon as possible.

Comment: I have latexified your answer for you. n.b. doing so is not an endorsement of its correctness ;)

Comment: Sorry but I was in a hurry. By the way, what is n.b.?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene